# La "gouène" ? Orthographe et géolocalisation

Tags: régionalismes

Une ***gouène*** (phonétiquement) (*0), c'est ainsi qu'au confluent du Lyonnais, de la Savoie et du Dauphiné j'entendais appeler une ruelle très étroite dévalant entre des maisons. (*1)

Je ne parviens pas à retrouver ce mot sur le net, ceux qui le connaissent pourraient-ils m'en préciser l'orthographe, la région d'élection ainsi que, le cas échéant une définition plus exacte.

*0 : Peut-être est-ce même *gouaine* sans pour autant rien à voir avec le *gwen* des Bretons.

*1 : Un peu comme ce que les Bourguignons nomment *treige* ou les Lyonnais *traboule*.

Comment: @Fólkvangr : Oui! Il n'est pas beau, je l'admets, mais c'est le seul terme qui me soit venu pour faire court dans un titre. Le texte de la question précise sa signification ici : Préciser la zone géographique où ce mot s'entend ou s'entendait autrefois.

Comment: Première fois que je vois ce mot personnellement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C'est peut-être une variante de *[gaîne](http://henrysuter.ch/glossaires/topoG0.html#gaine)* :

> **Gaîne**
>   Endroit reserré comme une gaine, ancien français gaïne, latin vulgaire *wagina, latin vagina, « gaine, fourreau de l´épée » [Jaccard].
>   **La Gaîne**, pâturage entre deux parois de rochers (Ormont-Dessus, district d´Aigle, Vaud).

Le [gw] initial serait alors un archaïsme de certains dialectes arpitans où la prononciation intermédiaire aurait subsisté, comme c'est le cas en italien (*guaina* : [↑gwa'ina]):

[Le phénomène des doublets](http://correspo.ccdmd.qc.ca/index.php/document/sursum-corda/curiosites-etymologiques-le-phenomene-des-doublets/)

> Le mot gaine (XIIIe) vient de l’évolution du latin vagina, mot prononcé en [w], puis, sous l’influence du germanique, en [gw] et enfin en [g].

Comment: +1 car l'hypothèse est crédible sur le plan sémantique. Je ne parviens néanmoins pas à m'expliquer d'où, dans cette hypothèse proviendrait le [ou] ou [w]. D'une ancienne graphie *g **u** a i ne ?

Comment: L'Arpitan! L'endroit dont je parle est situé just'pil'poil au beau milieu de la carte. **MERCI** beaucoup à toi pour cette contribution qui m'aura, en outre éclairé d'autres points plus ou moins connexes. J'attends d'avoir la possibilité de mettre un bounty sur cette question (encore 15heures) pour te l'accorder pour ta réponse. La satisfaction que j'éprouve valant plus que les 25Kudos que je peux conférer normalement.

Answer (score 2):

Le terme est peut-être à rapprocher de *veine* du latin *vena*, dont le dérivé en *-elle*, *venelle*, a le sens de ruelle.  D'après Wartburg (article *vēna*) *venelle*, attesté dans ce sens dès le 7e siècle dans un document latin du nord de le France, semble appartenir plutôt à la partie occidentale de la Galloromania.  Mais le terme a voyagé, il est repris en breton et on le trouve dans le sud de l'Italie, ayant été importé là-bas avec les Anjou, napolitain *vanella*, calabrais, sicilien *vanedda*.  Il n'est pas impossible non plus qu'il se trouve dans le domaine franco-provençal.

Resterait à expliquer la reformation de *venelle* en *veine* et le consonantisme en /gw/.

Comment: +1 pour l'idée. Il est vrai que le rapprochement entre les voies de communication et les vaisseaux sanguins sont productives, une grande rue étant, par opposition bien une *artère*. Coincidemment, il se trouve que la recherche de l'orthographe *guaine* sur google livres m'avait amené sur de vieux ouvrages de... médecine. Merci donc à toi pour cette bonne idée même si, pour l'heure, je crois que je me rangerai plutôt aux arguments de @jlliagre.